# Dump all function symbols and their base address to text file in trace32

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am trying to import all the function symbols in the elf with the function base address to a text file. 
I am using the below 2 commands to do that

```
PRinTer.FILE c:\temp\function_symbol.txt 
WinPrint.symbol.list.function
```

But in this process, full function name is getting terminated. I am getting output like this:

```
__________address________|path\symbol_|type_____________________|scope_|location|info
     P:C001608C--C00160E7|.sym_1\sym_2|(static void * ())       |module|static  |frame: * . push
```

I want the address and full path\symbol(2nd column). Please note that the symbol table is very big and increasing clip board size and selecting "To Clipboard All" will not work. I know that if I have the function base address , I can get the function name. But, in my implementation, I need to know both base address and function full name for better efficiency.

I want to know if it is possible to increase width of 2nd column via some command so that I get full function names after using winprint command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window sYmbol.List.Function has two columns (with white background) which have a flexible width. You can control the width of those flexible columns with the command `WinTABS`.

Thus, to export sYmbol.List.Function with a wide column for "path\symbol" use the following commands:

```
PRinTer.FILE c:\temp\function_symbol.txt ASCIIE
WinTABS 1000.
WinPrint.sYmbol.List.Function
```

By the way: The width of the address column on the left of the window (with gray background) is controlled via the 5th parameter of the `WinPOS` command.